# Passing smart pointer to a function requiring void*?

Tags: c++, memory

I need to use a library which defined a `register_cb` function taking a `void*` as it's parameter:

```
void register_cb(void* data, ...) {
}
```

Now I wish to pass it some data which I'm not storing on stack, easy way to illustrate is to call this from another function:

```
void my_processor_fn() {
  Foo foo;
  register_cb(&foo); //Invalid as foo will go out of scope.
}
```

So I can use the heap:

```
void my_processor_fn() {
  Foo* foo = new Foo();
  register_cb(foo); //Valid but I'll have to call delete to avoid memleak
}
```

And I can also use smart pointers:

```
void my_processor_fn() {
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
  register_cb(&foo); //Invalid, as unique_ptr will go out of scope and will delete foo.
}
```

How can I leverage smart pointers in these situation when I need to pass `void*` to a library function, and later the library will call my callback function with the address I have passed into `register_cb`?

Comment: In this case it's hard to get around the need for plain raw non-owning pointers and `new`/`delete`. Unless you can store the object in some way to ensure that its life-time is long enough (for example as a member of another object whose life-time is guaranteed to be long enough).

Comment: If you can't come up with a scope that accommodates the required lifetime, the only thing that I can come up with is a singleton that maintains a collection of your unique pointers and possibly allows you to release them when you know they are no longer needed. You'd pass the raw pointer to the library. The singleton could be a wrapper to the library interface.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can extend the lifetime of such objects by putting them in a class. Something like:

```
class MyProcess {
  public:
    MyProcess() : data_{std::make_unique<Foo>()} {}

    void my_processor_fn() {
        register_cb(data_.get());
    }

 private:
   std::unique_ptr<Foo> data_;
};
```

If you make this object then use it, everything will stay alive for you:

```
int main() {

   MyProcess my_process{};
   my_process.my_processor_fn();

   // pressumably some spinner that keeps the process alive while callbacks happen.
}
```

Comment: Could also fully make use of RAII and register the callback in the constructor and deregister it in the destructor, presuming that is necessary. (Or simpler, have a custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr` handle the deregistration, so that move semantics are automatically preserved.)

Comment: The myprocess object here is still created on the stack. Move this into the my_processor_fn() context and it too will go out of scope and take data_ with it. It does not solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @AviBerger why would you move the construction of the class to its own non static member function?

Comment: @user17732522 I think we need more question context, but yeah, both of those are possible.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox, I wouldn't. OP isn't doing this in main, but in the same fcn where the callback is being registered. And that fcn is returning before the lifetime needed for the object is over. OP needs lifetime extension and doesn't have currently have an appropriate place to park a unique_ptr. Also, we don't know that there is only one case of this. AFAICT, answer would be a static lifetime object to manage/hold these unique_ptr(s) until told they aren't needed anymore or program exit. Unless they can move this to main. I didn't read the OP that way.

Comment: I wasn't referring to your my_processor_fn() member function , but to the OP's which could be in some function in some thread in their program activated sometime during its operation when needed. If OP's case is really a one time at startup thing, then sure, your answer would be fine. Depends on what the OP's real situation is.